# How do I include extra Typescript declarations when I publish my package to NPM?

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a Typescript package that will be published on NPM, and I'd like to include some custom declarations along with the main declaration file that's generated by the Typescript compiler. However, when I install my package as a dependency in another project, Typescript only recognizes the generated declaration file, not the extra ones that I also want included in my project.

For example, assuming my package is called "my-package":

```
//In typings/my-interface.d.ts

declare module "my-package/interfaces" {
    export interface MyInterface { ... }
}
```

I can use that declaration throughout the original package without any problems by importing it with `import { MyInterface } from "my-package/interfaces"`. The problem is Typescript can't find `"my-package/interfaces"` when the package is installed as a dependency in another project. It only knows about `"my-package"`, even when the custom declarations are included in the package, and even when they're referenced from the compiled declaration.

As a real-world example, assume that [lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash) was written in Typescript and the author wanted to include declarations for all of the cherry-picked functions, along with the main lodash declaration file:

```
declare module "lodash/some" {
    export function ...
}

declare module "lodash/forOwn" {
    export function ...
}
```

Is it possible to include my custom declarations in an NPM package and have Typescript pick them up along with the compiled declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to not name your custom declaration file using "d.ts" but keep it to just declarations.

For example, try renaming `my-interface.d.ts` to `my-interface.ts`. When you compile tsc will generate `my-interface.d.ts` for you and you should be able to use it fine upstream.